# Unable to set the user password in AD using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, ssl, active-directory, spring-ldap

I have been trying to set/reset the user password for the user which I have created in AD. I am using spring boot Ldaptemplate in order to connect to my Active directory. I am successfully able to create the user but whenever I am trying to set the password, I get LDAP exception 53 which says this

```
javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A11E5, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0
```

I googled and followed the options mentioned in the different posts but no luck.

Below snippet for adding a new user.

```
 Name dn = buildDn(email);
 DirContextAdapter context = new DirContextAdapter(dn);
 context.setAttributeValues("objectclass", new String[] { "top", "person", "organizationalPerson", "user" });
 context.setAttributeValue("mail", email);          
 context.setAttributeValue("userPrincipalName", "user principal email");
 context.setAttributeValue("userAccountControl","544"); //somehow 512 throws an exception not sure of the reason (user account is enabled with no password required)

 context.setAttributeValue("sAMAccountName", "***");
 context.setAttributeValue("pwdLastSet", "-1");         

 ldapTemplate.bind(context);   //this creates user successfully.
```

Here are the things which I have tried so far:

1. Create a user.
2. Add the certificate to my JRE environment and verified that keytool command.
3. After that I say like this for modifying the user password.

```
 ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
 mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("UnicodePwd", pwdArray));
 context.modifyAttributes(dn, mods);
 ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(buildDn(email), new ModificationItem[] { mods[0] });

 LDAP://servername:636.
```

I still see the same error as LDAP 53 svcerror. Please let me know what am I missing here.

Comment: any thoughts,guys ?

Comment: Could you show how you prepare the `pwdArray`?

Comment: Are you using SSL/LDAPS? When updating pwd seems that ldap enforces to use ssl.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I figured out the issue. Unfortunately,  the certification was invalid that's why we got this error . After putting the right one, it worked for me. We can either put the certitficate into the Java environment else we can put into the system property